# UIWindow bounds/frame is null

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I'm creating a ios application without nib files and want to initialize the window in the application delegate like so:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

NSLog(@"%@", self.window.bounds);
```

The window shows up and I can see the green color I defined. When I debug self.window I get to see the bounds of the frame I just defined but when I want to access the bounds property, it returns null. Same with frame. What's the difference?

When I want to initialize a view next, it won't work because the frame/bounds are not defined to init that view:

```
// create root view
RootView* rootView = [[[RootView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds] autorelease];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yea, this is not going to work

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.window.bounds);
```

The window's bounds are not an object so %@ can't be used to display it :)

Try converting the `CGRect` into an `NSString *` first :

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.window.bounds));
```

That should give you a bit more debugging information to help you solve your problem :)

NB %@ simply calls `description` for the object and displays that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use format specifiers for `NSLog` frame:

```
NSLog(@"x=%.1f, y=%.1f, width=%.1f, height=%.1f", 
      self.window.bounds.origin.x, 
      self.window.bounds.origin.y, 
      self.window.bounds.size.width, 
      self.window.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: There's a helper method to do that for you - `NSStringFromCGRect` :) See the docs here for more : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW19